# Jake Sisko: Space Cosby?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, costume, object-identification, clothing

Did Jake Sisko ever wear this remarkably ugly sweater on screen, or was it just for a this photoshoot?

[image]

Comment: I find it ironic that this Star Trek Deep Space Nine publicity photo was not taken on the set of Deep Space Nine.

Comment: I cannot confirm or deny if he ever replicated any Jello

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## He really did wear it.

Jake wore it in the Season 4 episode ["Shattered Mirror"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shattered_Mirror_(episode)), where Jake and his father are captured and taken to the Mirror Universe.

Here is a screenshot of Jake wearing the sartorially-challenged garment:

[image]

(The woman with him is the Mirror Universe version of his mother.)

Comment: Now, the question is, *why* he wore it!

Comment: Not to mention how much they must have paid him to wear it ;P

Comment: @N_Soong, well,  he's obviously trying to blend in in the Mirror Universe,  where everything is opposite.

Comment: I wonder if it was considered as much of a fashion disaster in the Mirror Universe as it is in this one?

Comment: If I were a mirror I probably would have shattered at this image, too.